# Как отправить напоминание пользователям в указаное время

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Пишу бота для Телеграмм и хочу добавить напоминание пользователю.

**ПРИМЕР:** "Пользователь, через бота выберет событие, и когда ему о нем напомнить (задает дату и время для отправки сообщения). Бот должен прислать ему напоминание в указаное время. "

Как в PHP сделать так, чтобы скрипт исполнился именно в это время?

Или подскажите другие пути решения этой задачи?

Comment: ставите cron задачу на каждую минуту и в php проверяете если время совпадает со временем текущего то отправляете напоминание.

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение это крон, запишите в таблицу данные и опрашивайте с заданным периодом. Только подумайте над выборкой SQL чтобы когда таблица станет большой не получилось так что крон будет отставать на день. 
И снова как вариант, структура таблицы:

- `id [primary key int]`
- `careated_at [datatime]`
- `send_date [datatime]`
- `status [tinyint(1) index]`
- `user_id [int(11) index]`

Выборка будет примерно такая `SELECT user_id WHERE status = 1 AND send_date <= now()`

Comment: +, но datatime -> datetime {а еще лучше timestamp}, и careated_at -> created_at, index на user_id врятли нужен, когда он не учавствует во where, логичнее index(status, send_date)

Comment: @Firepro ну я думаю нужны какие-то данные о юзере, и если будем взять таблицы я бы добавил timestamp +